# Unable to parse Url with python urlparse

Tags: python, bash, urlparse

I am trying to write a small script that will take url as input and will parse it.

Following is my script

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys

from urlparse import urlsplit
url = sys.argv[1]
parseUrl = urlsplit(url)
print 'scheme  :', parseUrl.scheme
print 'netloc  :', parseUrl.netloc
```

But when I execute this script with `./myscript http://www.example.com`

it shows following error.

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'scheme'
```

I am new to `python/scripting`, where am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Python version that I am using is `Python 2.7.5`

Comment: You are not using 2.7.5. I've just downloaded and compiled it, and your code works fine with it, just as it does with my default Python, which is 2.7.6. You can check your version using `python --version`. Make sure `/usr/bin/env python` returns the right python too.

Comment: I have executed following 
`python --version` which returned me Python 2.7.5
Then I have execute following 
`usr/bin/env python`
which returned me following 
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin

Comment: What happens if you add `print sys.version` to your script? Also, how are you running the script - interactively at a prompt?

Comment: yeah you are right, python version is `Python 2.4.3`.
I will upgrade it to 2.7. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you already have the right Python installed somewhere. You simply need to change your #! line to that Python e.g. "#!/usr/bin/python2.7" or whatever is the right path

Comment: Python's urllib.parse is old and doesn't handle unicode or IPv6 addresses. uritools is reportedly better: http://pythonhosted.org/uritools/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want scheme. Instead in this case you want to access the `0` index of the tuple and the `1` index of the tuple.

```
print 'scheme  :', parseUrl[0]
print 'netloc  :', parseUrl[1]
```

`urlparse` uses the `.scheme` and `.netloc` notation, [`urlsplit` instead uses a tuple (refer to the appropriate index number):](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit)

> This is similar to urlparse(), but does not split the params from the
>   URL. This should generally be used instead of urlparse() if the more
>   recent URL syntax allowing parameters to be applied to each segment of
>   the path portion of the URL (see RFC 2396) is wanted. A separate
>   function is needed to separate the path segments and parameters. This
>   function returns a 5-tuple: (addressing scheme, network location,
>   path, query, fragment identifier).
>
> The return value is actually an instance of a subclass of tuple. This
>   class has the following additional read-only convenience attributes:
>
> ```
> Attribute Index   Value                               Value if not present
> scheme      0       URL scheme specifier                empty string
> netloc      1       Network location part               empty string
> path        2       Hierarchical path                   empty string
> query       3       Query component                     empty string
> fragment    4       Fragment identifier                 empty string
> username            User name                           None
> password            Password                            None
> hostname            Host name (lower case)              None
> port                Port number as integer, if present  None
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs, it sounds like you are using Python 2.4, which does not have the attributes added. The other answered missed off the critical bit from the docs:

> New in version 2.2.
>
> Changed in version 2.5: Added attributes to return value.

You will have to access the tuple parts by index or unpacking:

```
scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment = urlsplit(url)
```

However, you should really be upgrading to Python 2.7. Python 2.4 is no longer supported.

Comment: I have updated my question with the python version I am using.